# Change car size on runtime in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

Cars are moving on the road, and I want to use a button to change the scale of the cars.
Once I press the button, the scale of all the cars that are in the system and are being produced by the source should change.

**My approach**

**1.** I make a variable "carSize" and put it in "car" 3Objact properties "Additional Scale." shown in image below.
[image]

**2** Then in "Main" I put this code in a button.

```
LineCarAgent LineCar = new LineCarAgent();
LineCar.set_carSize(11);
traceln("New car size " + LineCar.carSize);
```

Now, when I run the model and press the button, I can see the new value printed in the console, but the size of the car does not change, neither for existing cars nor for upcoming cars.

Answer (score 2):

If you know which car you want to have the shape scale change, use:

```
cars.get(i).car.setScale(s);
```

Comment: I want to change scale of all the cars that are in the system and getting produce by source, once I press the button.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a loop to go through "cars" population and change the scale of all the cars one by one.

The only issue is that if we include "loop" in the button, then only the scale of the existing population will change. So what we can do is put the loop in the cyclic event to keep changing the scale of the new coming car.

**Step 1:** Create an cyclic event and put this code in the action

```
for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++) {
    cars.get(i).car.setScale(0.9);
}
```

**Step 2:** We don't want the code in the event to start executing unless we press the button, so "on startup" write `event.suspend()`; and in the button action, write `event.restart();`.

Now event will only start once we press the button. Which means that all the cars scale will only change when we press the button.